# Is it intentional that the CiviCRM public theme always the same as the CiviCRM Administration theme for administrators?

Tags: admin, theme, drupal-9

I notice that the theme Administrators of CiviCRM get is that set for Administration, even if they are in a public part of CiviCRM, e.g. CiviCRM Home. Is this intentional?

Comment: I do not think it is and have not observed this behaviour yet. Probably you have alreeady cleared the drupal caches?!

Comment: Just ran https:/<drupal site>/civicrm/report/instance/<id>?reset=1&force=1 as an administrator and got the administrator theme, and the same link as a non-administrator and got the public theme.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're referring to the Drupal configuration setting under Appearance, where you can "Choose theme for CiviCRM administration/backend pages."

The main confusion here is that 'civicrm administration/backend pages' isn't well-defined, the definition depends on not just the url, but also, who's accessing it.

For your reports example, I expect what is happening is that CiviCRM considers them 'adminstration/backend', but that you have given access to the report to "non-adminstrators", and you haven't also given them access to your administration theme. So non-administrators will access the reports with the fall back to the 'front-end' theme.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One challenge is that some themes do not let you update profile definitions - there is an error somewhere on the page so you can't fill in the field definition form.